# Does imshow have side effects in Matlab? And how can I resolve them?

Tags: image, matlab, side-effects

I have two axes let's say `A1` and `A2`, and on `A2` I have an image that displays with `imshow`, on `A1` I display something entirely different with `imagesc`, and it produces a different result color-wise when A2 is used. Here is some example code, likely the shortest example:

```
a = zeros(1); 
[b,bmap] = imread('F.bmp');
c = figure();
d = axes('Parent',c,'Position',[0,0,.5,1]);
e = axes('Parent',c,'Position',[.5,0,.5,1]);


axes(d);
imagesc(a);
pause();
axes(e);
imshow(b,bmap);
pause();
cla(d);
axes(d);
imagesc(a);
figure();
axes();
imagesc(a);
```

The image a displays differently after b is shown, but when displayed in a different figure it displays normally. How can I fix this?

Comment: may be its because of your matlab version, what is your matlab version?

Comment: 2015a I think I found why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in I think it is because providing the map, `bmap` to `imshow` causes the `figure.Colormap` value to change, so this can be fixed by typing `colormap default` after an `imshow` command.